# SMTPSenderRefused at /password_reset/

Tags: django

SMTPSenderRefused at /password_reset/
(530, b'5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError r13-v6sm6514618wmf.35 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzuZy.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you saved your email/password in environ variable for the first time. Please close your terminal and open it again and run the server, I hope this will solve your problem. I have run into the same problem and solved issues just like this.

Answer (score -1):

it is so cool that you are using stackoverflow. Please look around for already solved issues that are similiar to yours before posting a new question. We should use the resources we already have. (You don't open new gas station everytime you refuel your car, right? ok, sorry for exaggeration, but you get the idea)

what you need in this case is, most of the time, to allow access less secure apps to your gmail account: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

but in best practice, you should use services that are focused on this. e.g. [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or other email services.

Comment: oui,j'ai deja Autorisé les applications moins sécurisées ....mais j'ai toujours affronter le meme probleme

Comment: @medzios Please in english :)

Comment: yes, I already allowed less secure applications .... but I still face the same problem